# UNIX how to resume a process using process ID?

Tags: unix, shell

I have a problem to resume processes.

When I tried to get a process to come to the foreground using `jobs`, it works, but if I close the shell and start it again, I don't have my process in the jobs list.

I know just the process name and its ID. How can I get it to foreground?

Answer (score 7):

I think once you detach your terminal from a process by logging out, you lose the ability to re-attach.  Unless you are using a utility like screen to manage your sessions.

This may help....

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process

Answer (score 3):

If you start the process originally using `screen` you can reattach later:

1. Run `screen -D -R`
2. Run your command in there.
3. Press `Ctrl A` then `D` to disconnect from `screen`. The process will continue running and you will be returned to the original shell.

Then, later, from any terminal:

1. Run `screen -D -R`
2. You'll be back in the screen shell, where your program will be running from earlier.

If the process is already running or you don't have the ability to start it via `screen`, there is also a [tool called `reptyr`](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/) that can do this. You can use it on an existing process, then close the terminal, then open a new terminal and use it to reattach the existing process to the new terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not using `screen` and that the process was stopped using the "SIGTSTP" or "SIGSTOP" signal, you could always try to send the "CONTINUE" signal to the process like this :

```
kill -SIGCONT $PID
```

where `$PID` is your process id.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the terminal, the process is sent `SIGHUP`, the hangup signal. Unless you are using a utility like `screen` or `nohup`, or the program is especially oddly-behaving, `SIGHUP` will cause the process to gracefully terminate.

Answer (score 1):

If you threw the process into the background, you can just type fg to resume where you left off, otherwise you can disown the program, open screen, reattach the PID using screen, and finally use reptyr to get the process back while in screen

```
$ disown yourprogram          # Detach yourprogram from the shell
$ screen                      # Launch screen
$ reptyr $(pgrep yourprogram) # Get back the process
```